# Redirecting to another action if the user isn't in a given role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have three roles in my application. I have a index page, which i want to be accesible only to unregistered users. So when a registered users tries to go to the index page my idea is to redirect him to his index page instead.

I am trying to do it like this :

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (User.IsInRole("CompanyAdministrator"))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "CompaniesController");

            }
            else if (User.IsInRole("Employee"))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "EmployeeController");
            }
            return View();
```

So when I am logged in as a CompanyAdministrator and I try to go to Home/Index, intead of getting redirected I am getting a

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.

and the url looks like this : `http://localhost:49858/CompaniesController`

Sorry if the question is too subjective, but I couldn't find an explenation for this issue, and I can't explaing it myself.

Any tips on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `Controller` suffix. Simply use the controller name without `Controller` part.

This should work.

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Companies");
```

The `Controller` suffix is used to by the MVC framework to detect all the controllers when the app starts (to register routes). Other than that, an end user (the one who codes) **usually** does not need to use the full class name anywhere!

Apparently, nameof (C# 6) [cannot be used to get the Controller class name](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2586) !

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add 'Controller' in controller name. It should be

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Companies");
```